# Lufthansa online check-in for multiple passengers and legs

Tags: air-travel, airlines, check-in, lufthansa

Later this year, my girlfriend and I will be flying with Lufthansa on a transatlantic flight. To keep this question as generic as possible, let's call the itinerary A-FRA-C, with A (and FRA, of course) being within the Schengen area and C obviously being outside Schengen. Our ticket includes both legs (and the return flights) and it includes both me and my girlfriend.

AFAIK, with Lufthansa, you can check-in online 23 hours before the flight, which is also when you can pick a seat for free. My questions are:

1. Will we able to check in both of us at the same time (as in, with one login to the web form), making sure we can get seats next to each other?
2. Will we be able to check in to our **second** leg 23 hours before the scheduled departure of the **first** leg, or do we have to check in twice?

I'm especially interested in the answer to the second question (both for personal reasons and in general, since this would give passengers with a feeder flight an advantage when it comes to picking a "good" seat compared to passengers flying directly from a hub).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You check in for both legs at once, within 23 hours of your first departure.

All passengers on the same reservation can check in at once.

Small correction: you are probably on the same reservation but you have separate tickets.  This will be reflected in two distinct e-ticket numbers.

Comment: For clarity, that you have one reservation but technically two tickets is perfectly normal and nothing you should have the slightest concern over.  In fact, pretend you don't even know :)

Comment: Yep, we do indeed have one reservation (six-character booking code), but two different "etix" numbers. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I can confirm that this is correct based on my own experience a couple of months ago.  We had flights LHR-MUC-TBS with five people (2 adults and 3 children) on one booking - and could check in all of us 23 hours before the first departure.

Comment: Separately, I can confirm that Lufthansa's online check in process is horrendously slow and user-unfriendly even for one traveller; when there are multiple travellers involved, it's much worse.  On our return flights, I didn't manage to complete the whole thing and just ignored it all and went to the airport to check in there.

Comment: @AleksG I've also had trouble with their online check-in, and TAP even had trouble once checking my wife in for her second leg of a TAP/Lufthansa itinerary after I tried to check her in online.  I always forget that if you indicate that you're a resident but not a citizen of the US then they require a green card number and prevent you from changing the answer to "are you a resident of the US."  My wife lives in the US but has no green card.  I suppose this stems from their developers not understanding the differences between US green cards and German residence permits.

Answer (score 2):

If your booking is on one ticket (which you imply), at the check-in time for the first flight, you can check-in for all the flights, and will get all the boarding passes (you actually cannot check in only for the first leg, they only offer all together).

Note that there *might* be reasons why - even though you can check in online and pick your seats - you will not get a boarding pass to print (or electronically), because of the target country, visa regulations, etc. In that case, you will get your boarding passes only at the airport, when they have physically verified your passports/visas/etc.

Answer (score 0):

I've flown multi-leg flights with several airlines, including Lufthansa. None of them has ever made me check in for the different legs separately: it's always been that you check in for the whole journey as soon as check-in for the first leg opens.

Comment: Just because I recently experienced it: Air India does actually make you check-in separately. As in, for each leg, the check-in opens 48 hours before departure.

Comment: @TheWolf How bizarre. And inconvenient.